# R - Change key colours in ancova (HH package)

Tags: r, plot, lattice, trellis

I'm using the `ancova()` function in R (**HH** package) with a factor with more levels than the default 7 colours for **lattice** graphics.

This means that `ancova()` fails to plot some of my panels as it can't find a colour to use. I've tried `trellis.par.set` with `simpleTheme`, but cannot get more than 7 colours to register in `ancova()`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The package author/maintainer is very responsive. Since this has attracted little attention in is first half day I would send an email.